# Divergence of harmonic like series

Tags: calculus

How to show that the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{5/6+2n}$$

diverges?

Comment: $\frac 56 +2n \lt 2(n+1) $.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $\frac 56+2n<3n$ for all $n\geq 1$. Hence
$$\frac{1}{\frac 56+2n}>\frac{1}{3n}.$$

Since
$$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{3n}=\frac 13\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}=+\infty,$$
we must also have
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\frac 56+2n}=+\infty.$$